# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet | APScheduler

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

I have this APScheduler code:

```
import atexit
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from main.utils import run_employee_import

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(run_employee_import, "interval", minutes=2)
scheduler.start()

# Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

When I add this code to `settings.py` to run it when the app starts to run, it gives me the following error:

```
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

PS: I did not include the `run_employee_import` code because I tested it already (replaced its content with a simple `pass`) and nothing changed, so it is irrelevant to the error.

Comment: please attach your traceback?

Comment: There was no traceback except this exception (happened on the console). Anyways, I used the apps.py to run the task instead, check the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I completely changed the way I run the scheduler. And it worked, let me share the solution with you:

I create a .py file inside the app:

```
app/bulk_task.py
```

I create a start function and put the schedule code in it:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from main.utils import **<MY_TASK>**
    
def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(**<MY_TASK>**, "interval", minutes=5)
    scheduler.start()
```

Then I open the apps.py file of my app, and I add the following code:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MainConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "main"

    def ready(self):
        from . import bulk_task

        bulk_task.start()
```

And that's it ;)